# WCF client - why am I getting this error?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am trying to use a web service (https/ssl/basicHttpBinding). I add service reference without issues and call it asynchronously. I pass the instance of the client to the CallBack. I get this error when trying to get the result from the service at the CallBack:

> Header
>   `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:Action`
>   for ultimate recipient is required but
>   not present in the message.

```
var Result = client.BeginTheServiceOperation(header, CallBack, client);

private static void CallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   var client = ar.AsyncState as MyServiceSoapClient;
   var result = client.EndTheServiceOperation(ar); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the service?

Comment: I've updated the question with the call to BeginTheServiceOperation. Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire method that calls BeingTheServiceOperation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the service was expecting SOAP 1.1 and by default WCF uses SOAP 1.2. I needed to create a new custom binding, passing that configuration in and it all worked ok. This pointed me in the right direction: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f3707303-4f35-4079-ac0b-eba4717cada8

Comment: You can mark this self-answer as the answer.  As the FAQ says, "It’s also perfectly fine to \[...\] answer your own question".

Answer (score 1):

This is an indication that you have not applied the the proper message configuration options to your binding. The service is expecting a SOAP message with WS-Addressing headers, but apparently your client is not passing them. Since the default binding would pass them, I have to assume you've changed your binding in some way that would prevent them from being passed.

If more assistance is required, please also add your binding configuration code/config XML to the original post.